# Filter for each item in list to check if it is in a list of ID's

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to get only results where for every game's categories that category is in a list of id's, doing the following does not work. Game.categories is a hybrid_property that gives me the game's categories.

This is the query I am doing expecting to get a list of all the games that have at least one category in the list of ID's I specify.

```
games = Game.query \
  .filter([category.id for category in Game.categories].in_([1, 2, 3])) \
  .paginate(page, current_app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'], False)
```

My models.py is this. Note that each game's categories depends on the count that category has been defined by a user.

```
class CategoryUpvote(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
  category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
  game_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('game.id'))

class Category(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(32))

class Game(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  title = db.Column(db.String(255), index=True, unique=True)

  category_upvotes = db.relationship('CategoryUpvote', backref='category', lazy='dynamic', cascade="save-update, merge, delete")

  def add_upvote(self, category, user):
    if not self.is_upvoted(category, user):
      upvote = CategoryUpvote(category_id=category.id, game_id=self.id, user_id=user.id)
      db.session.add(upvote)
    else:
      upvote = self.category_upvotes.filter(CategoryUpvote.category_id == category.id, CategoryUpvote.user_id == user.id, CategoryUpvote.game_id == self.id).first()
      db.session.delete(upvote)

  def is_upvoted(self, category, user):
    return self.category_upvotes.filter(CategoryUpvote.category_id == category.id, CategoryUpvote.user_id == user.id, CategoryUpvote.game_id == self.id).count() > 0

  @hybrid_property
  def categories(self):
    return Category.query \
      .filter(CategoryUpvote.game_id == self.id, CategoryUpvote.category_id == Category.id) \
      .group_by(Category.id) \
      .order_by(db.func.count(CategoryUpvote.game_id).desc()) \
      .limit(5) \
      .all()
```

I get this error

```
'list' object has no attribute 'in_'
```

How can I somehow run filter for each category a game has? for example

```
.filter(Game.categories[0].in_([1, 2, 3]), Game.categories[1].in_([1, 2, 3]), Game.categories[2].in_([1, 2, 3])) \
```

Also if Game had each Category as a foreign key I could do something like this

```
Game.query.join(Category).filter(Category.id.in_([1, 2, 3]))
```

How to do something similar with a hybrid_property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute `Game.categories`, though meant as a `hybrid_property`, does not work in SQL context. When used to create [SQL expression objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html) at class level it still performs an actual query against the database, returning a list of `Category` objects instead. Most of your errors result from this fact.

In addition it essentially performs a join (using the pre SQL-92  style) between `Game` and `CategoryUpvote`, returning 5 top voted categories from *all* games. It would make the property a lot more usable in general, if it were to return the `Query` without materializing to a list:

```
class Game(db.Model):

  @hybrid_property
  def categories(self):
    return Category.query \
      .join(CategoryUpvote) \
      .filter(CategoryUpvote.game_id == self.id) \
      .group_by(Category.id) \
      .order_by(db.func.count(CategoryUpvote.game_id).desc()) \
      .limit(5)
```

You would then access the list of categories of a `Game` instance using

```
game.categories.all()
```

or simply iterate over it directly. With the hybrid property returning a query you can now use it to generate correlated subqueries, for example. Then you could turn your attempt to filter categories based on a list of ids in to the predicate "the difference between given ids and category ids of a game identified by `id` is empty", or in other words all given ids are contained in the set of top-5 category ids of a game:

```
# A portable way to build a (derived) table of ids. Use VALUES
# instead, if supported.
ids = union(*[select([literal(i).label('id')]) for i in [1, 2, 3]])

Game.query.filter(~exists(
    ids.select()
        .except_(Game.categories
            .correlate(Game)
            .with_entities(Category.id)
            .subquery()
            .select())))
```

Please note that

> I want to get only results where for every game's categories that category is in a list of id's

and

> This is the query I am doing expecting to get a list of all the games that have at least one category in the list of ID's I specify

are not the same thing, and the example above is written with the former in mind, though the strict interpretation (**every** category in list) would require using symmetric difference.

In order to get the latter you would query using the predicate "the intersection between given ids and category ids of a game identified by `id` is **not** empty", so you would swap the [`except_()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.except_) to [`intersect()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.intersect) and remove the NOT operator `~` in front of [`exists()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.exists) – because if something is not empty, a row or rows exists.

Answer (score 1):

The problem facing is because you are trying to run a query using a generator

```
category.id.in_([1,2,3]) for category in Game.categories
```

To give you a small example. When you run the following code you get the desired output of 0 to 5 in a list.

```
>>> print([a for a in range(5)])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now if you do remove the square bracket then

```
>>> print(a for a in range(5))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x102829f10>
```

You can see that the output is a generator expression. Same is the case with your code, since you are not evaluation python is sending it as a generator object

I don't have experience with sqlalchemy, But I feel what you are trying to achieve you can do something like this:

```
for category in Game.categories
    result.append(category.id.in_([1, 2, 3]))

games = Game.query \
  .filter(Game.id.in_(result)) \
  .paginate(page, current_app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'], False)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but a problem still persists. I am trying to run filter for each category each game has, and have edited my code above to elaborate.

Comment: @Psychodrama I have updated the code. I don't have any idea about sqlalchemy, so you might need to check the syntax. And also the for loop I have written is not something recommended. I couldn't understand what you are trying to achieve hence I wrote the loop. I would prefer doing it using database using join